# How to parse date from string using ParseExact?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse a date from a string formatted as the following `"17/9/2020, 13:00:00"` as a valid `DateTime` object, but after trying to use `.ParseExact` and setting the date pattern i'm getting the error:

> String `'17/9/2020, 13:00:00'` was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`..

By using `.ParseExact` i'm trying to do the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(quando.quando, "dd/MM/yyy, HH:mm:ss", null)
```

Comment: Your format string has `MM`, which means it expects a two-digit month. "9" only has a single digit. I suspect you want `M` instead of `MM` - and probably `d` instead of `dd` too. It's *likely* you want `yyyy` though. (I doubt that you have any dates before the year 1000.)

Comment: 99.9% you need `yyyy`

Comment: @JonSkeet the missing `y` was a syntax error, thanks for letting me know, actually i had to use single `d` as you suggested as for days like 8 september the service was passing `8/9/2020` instead of 08

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 1 `M` too much and 1 `y` too few:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("17/9/2020, 13:00:00", "dd/M/yyyy, HH:mm:ss", null)
```

the format `MM` expects an input of **always** two digits for the month like `09` (september)

If you take only 1 M it will also parse a 2 digit month like december:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("17/12/2020, 13:00:00", "dd/M/yyyy, HH:mm:ss", null)
```

EDIT: taking this from Jon Skeets comment: you should probably also use a single `d` for days since your date string will likely exhibit the following format `"7/9/2020, 13:00:00"`.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("7/9/2020, 13:00:00", "dd/M/yyyy, HH:mm:ss", null)
```

Comment: will it be valid anyway if the string will be `17/10/2020` if i use single `M`?

Comment: @KasperJuner Yes, it will be ok.

Comment: @KasperJuner yes it will, but it does not work like this with the year digits ;) if you have 4 you have to specify also 4 times `y`

Comment: the missing `y` was a syntax error, thought i had put it. anyway didn't knew about single `M` that was parsing two digits too. i'd accept your answer in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Your format isn't correct. See an example here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ppjvX

You should use this format "dd/M/yyyy, HH:mm:ss". "MM" expects 2 digist like "09". Also 4 "y" symbols are required.